# Strategy for cross-language (java and c#) object serialization

Tags: c#, java, serialization, cross-platform

I'm working on a project where I'll need to serialize some data in a java 6 app and deserialize it a c# 2.0 app.  Is there a strategy or something already in existence I can look at that would allow me to do this with these two languages?  I'm guessing they both support XML serialization but I really need it to be binary serialized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Protocol buffers would be a good option here. On the C# side, I would recommend Jon Skeet's [dotnet-protobufs](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port) for this use-case, since it has the same API on both sides (his C# version is a port of the Google Java version, part of the core distribution). If you want the C# to be more "typical .NET", then [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) may help.

(the wire format is obviously identical between versions; the API may vary)

Small, fast, efficient, [portable](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns).

For info, I *know* that protobuf-net has .NET 2.0 support; I honestly haven't tried this on Jon's version, but I *expect* it would - there isn't much that you need 3.0/3.5 for in protobuf.

Comment: Yes, I target .NET 2.0, as well as Silverlight 2+ and Compact Framework 2+ (IIRC - the CF version may be 3.5).

Answer (score 9):

[Protocol Buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) ([Google Site](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/))

[Java Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html)

[Jon Skeet's C# Port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/)

[Marc Gravell's C# Port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

Upsides: Fast and you can bug quite some people that are involved with this thing on SO.. ;-)

Let me exploit Marc's project site: [Performance is quite acceptable](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance)..

Comment: Yeah, like Marc and I ever show up here. 'Tis pure fluke that we happen to have both looked at this question.

Answer (score 6):

The default binary serialization of each language is incompatible so you will not be able to use that.

There are many cross-language serialization technologies that support Java, C#, and other languages:

- [JSON](http://www.json.org/)
- [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/)
- [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/)

Of these, JSON is not binary but very efficient for a string-based language. Thrift and Protocol Buffers are binary and have a very compact representation.

Answer (score 4):

You could try Hessian:

http://hessian.caucho.com/index.xtp

It's binary, and supports Java, C++, and several other languages. I've never used it myself, but came across it, thought it was interesting, and bookmarked it...

Answer (score 3):

Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html) is something that you could look into. You will need to check into the state of the usability of the C# implementation, but in all other respects, I think that it meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

you can use BSON if you really need the data as binary...

http://bsonspec.org/implementations.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wox cross platform serialization library (https://github.com/codelion/wox), it is based on native XML serializers for Java and C#.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe binary serialization will work as C# and Java have no idea of each others native types.

Comment: "Binary serialization" is not necessarily the same thing as "type/metadata serialization". Many binary formats don't depend on the types used at any implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo most of the other answers here as far as Google protocol buffers is concerned. But I ended up using a program called protostuff at the Java end instead of Google's own Java implementation, and I also added the name of the (outermost) class as a prefix to the protocol buffers data to make the data self-describing for deserialization. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17923846/253938