# WPF Technology Stack

Tags: wpf, stack

I have the below stack:

tomcat+java 6+ spring on the server side.
and WPF on the client side.

we can add additional frameworks on both sides if needed.

**Is there any way to make the WPF talk to java server directly and data can be transferred similar to binary transfer in flex remoting?i.e. java object to c# object serialization with good performace**

I know xml is one of the other ways.

I have read [an similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001405/strategy-for-cross-language-java-and-c-object-serialization). But the performance is not discussed on the article.

Regards,
Shah

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you would be able to communicate between two ends when one uses `RMI` and other uses `Remoting`. I recommend you use `Web Service` instead.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? I want to return an object of java say "return new EmployeeVO();" and want it converted to a C# object, A similar thing is achieved by flex, where a java object is converted into a counter flex actionscript object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/). It's a binary protocol, implemented in java and .net (and many more). Fits well with Spring as seen [here](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/42551).

Comment: i am concerned about the maturity of this project. The website seems  unmaintained and lack of documentation does not help.